# запросить из /dev/urandom

Tags: c++, linux

Как получить беззнаковый 1 байт, знаковый 1 байт?
Как получить singned long long и unsigned long long.
нужно ли запрашивать по 1 байту и "докладывать"?

Какой принцип работы urandom, он хранит в себе все байты (0..255) но в случайном порядке, верно? Или от 0 до потолка 4 байт? Или от 0 до половины потолка 4 байт (как в окнах rand())? Или ещё как-то иначе?
При перезапуске программы будут другие числа или те же? Если те же, то как начать сразу с N-ной итерации?

/dev/random не предлагать, интересует именно urandom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый байт из /dev/urandom это случайный набор из 8 бит.

Поэтому просто читайте байты  в память переменной нужного вам типа.

В отличии от /dev/random в /dev/urandom всегда есть данные, поэтому можно использовать буферизированный ввод без опасения нарваться на непредсказуемо долгое ожидание ответа
(например, `fread(&var, sizeof(var), 1, fdev_urandom);`)